# odata API $count deserializing issue in azure synapse copy activity

Tags: azure-data-factory, odata, office365api

I am trying to get count from API call where I used /$count keyword. I want to capture this count for further validation and using copy activity.
But unfortunately I am getting the following issue.

Error occurred when deserializing source JSON file ''. Check if the data is in valid JSON object format.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks
[image: rest api response]
[image: Copy error output]

[image: Linked service for rest api]

[image: Web activity config]
[image: Error Message]

Comment: How do you want to further validate? Where do you want to capture this value?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot provided, the issue is in the response of the API. It has a scalar value `20`. But copy activity source dataset, expects a `Json` data or table format data. It should have key and value (column name and value). Only then, data can be copied to sink dataset. You can use web activity in ADF to get the API's value and use it in further activities in ADF.

[image]

**Output of Web activity Output:**

```
{
    "Response": "20",
    "ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders": {
        ........
        }
}
```

You can use the expression `@activity('Web1').output.Response` in the further activities in data factory to validate it.

Comment: Hi Aswin, thanks for the response. I have already tried this . But I have an API configured on OAuth client credential and I am unable to configure web activity using linked service. It would be a great help if you could help me out here. I have added a screenshot of linked service as well

Comment: Also, I do not find enough detail to call rest api using linked service from synapse notebook as well.

Comment: You can run only code that are in notebook using synapse notebook activity

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of API response? `services.odata....../../people` **Don't include $count in the URL**

Comment: I have used the same URL in the URL property of web activity and base URL of linked service. Error screenshot is attached

Comment: For the api , `services.odata......./people` what is the response?

Comment: Dont include `/$count` parameter in that API

Comment: I have not used /$count in the response. Error screenshot is attached . Missing API key header. error code 2108

Comment: Can you try that in browser and share like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRTVc.png)

Comment: The actual API is proxied one and not able to query from browser as it requires token and client credentials

Comment: Okay. Then, Give the URL without count and check in source dataset of copy activity. CLick data preview

Comment: That is working fine. I need count of the records though. This api was developed in such a way that it limits 20k records. So in order to set pagination rules, I need the total number of records returned by API.

Comment: Can you share the sample format of API response? Does that include count in the header?